# Using javascript on new element created by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a field location and with that I have a button add new location.On clicking that button a new textbox for that field opens.Now what I have done is I am using autofill address on that location field but autofill works for only first textbox not those textboxes which I am creating using jquery

Below is the html code

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
 <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Preferred Work Location</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
<input type="text" id="loc" name="Work_Location[]" class="form-control" >
</div>
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Locations</button>
</div>
</div>
```

and below is the code to create new textboxes

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Preferred Work Location</label><div class="col-md-3"> <input type="text" id="loc" name="Work_Location[]" class="form-control"  ></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

and Below is the autofill code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-AU"></script>
    <script>
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#loc")[0], {});

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place.address_components);
        });
    </script>
```

What the above code does is gives suggestions while filling location

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery on mathod attach event to every single element selected in selector part separatly. If you add new one you need to reaatach the event there.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
container = $('<div class="form-group"></div>');
container.append('<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Preferred Work Location</label><div class="col-md-3"> <input type="text" id="loc" name="Work_Location[]" class="form-control"  ></div>');
remove_box = $('<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>').on('click', remove_field);
container.append(remove_box);
        $(wrapper).append(container); //add input box
    }
});
function remove_field(e) {//user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
}

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", remove_field);
});
</script>
```

Something like this. I didn't check the syntax so fix what is necesary.